# How do I stretch a component over multiple columns using GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I've been learning about layouts in Java Swing and am currently making a simple calculator. I will be using a text field for input/output and I want to stretch it over 2 columns(i am using three total) but when I try to stretch it, it resizes items in the first column. Here's the code and a screenshot.

Screenshot of the app:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCACd.png]

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame{

    JButton but1, but2, but3, but4, but5, but6,
        but7, but8, but9, but0, butPlus, butMinus,
        clearAll;

    JTextField textResult;

    int num1, num2;

    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        new Calculator();
        
    }

    public Calculator(){
            
        this.setSize(400,400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Calculator");
    
        JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
    
        thePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    
        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridheight = 1;
        gridConstraints.weightx = 50;
        gridConstraints.weighty = 100;
        gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gridConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    
        textResult = new JTextField("0", 20);
    
        Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18);
        textResult.setFont(font);
    
        but1 = new JButton("1");
        but2 = new JButton("2");
        but3 = new JButton("3");
        but4 = new JButton("4");
        but5 = new JButton("5");
        but6 = new JButton("6");
        but7 = new JButton("7");
        but8 = new JButton("8");
        but9 = new JButton("9");
        butPlus = new JButton("+");
        but0 = new JButton("0");
        butMinus = new JButton("-");
        clearAll = new JButton("C");
    
        thePanel.add(clearAll, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
    
        thePanel.add(textResult, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = 1;
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 1;
        thePanel.add(but1, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
        thePanel.add(but2, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 2;
        thePanel.add(but3, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 2;
        thePanel.add(but4, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
        thePanel.add(but5, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 2;
        thePanel.add(but6, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 3;
        thePanel.add(but7, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
        thePanel.add(but8, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 2;
        thePanel.add(but9, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 4;
        thePanel.add(butPlus, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
        thePanel.add(but0, gridConstraints);
        gridConstraints.gridx = 2;
        thePanel.add(butMinus, gridConstraints);
    
    
        this.add(thePanel);
    
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: (1+) Reasonable example. However, in the future an MRE is used to separate the problem from the application. We are not interested in your application, only the minimal code to demonstrate the problem.  You have a sizing question. Do you need all 5 rows of buttons to demonstrate this, or will the first two rows demonstrate the problem. The less code we (or you) have to look at, the easier it is to spot the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:

Swing offsets/indexes start at 0.

Normally when people use the GridBagLayout the gridx/gridy would start at 0.

However, I see that you are using gridx/gridy with starting values of 1. This should work. It will just mean that column 0 and row 0 will have a size of 0.

To be consistent with how most people use the GridBagLayout, you may want to  change your code to use 0 as the starting offset for gridx/gridy.

My advice below assumes you will convert your code to use 0 as the offsets for the grids.

```
gridConstraints.gridx = 5;
gridConstraints.gridwidth = 20;
thePanel.add(textResult, gridConstraints);
```

You only have 3 columns. You can't just randomly give a component:

1. a gridx of 5, it can only be 0, 1, 2. In this case you want 1
2. a gridwidth of 20, it can only be 1, 2, 3. In this case you want 2.

If you keep 1 as the starting grid offset then you would need to use 2 for the gridx.

Edit:

> it resizes items in the first column

I think the issue is the following:

```
textResult = new JTextField("0", 20);
```

The 20 tells the text field to size itself to display 20 "W" characters (which makes the text field large relative to the buttons.

Therefore the buttons in columns 1 and 2 will be half the size of the text field.

Maybe try:

```
textResult = new JTextField("0", 10);
```

to see if that is any better.

Or maybe a better option is to just use:

```
textResult = new JTextField("0");
```

Now the size of the text field will be controlled by the size of the buttons.

Comment: I've implemented the changes but the problem still persists.

Comment: Post a proper [mre]. We can't copy/paste/compile and test the provided code. You are missing the imports, class name and main() method.

Comment: Added everything sorry for the delay this is my first post.

Answer (score -1):

Change the line

textResult = new JTextField("0", 20);

to

textResult = new JTextField("0");

The problem was that your text field has a minimum width that is larger than 2 of your columns combined so it's stretching the 2 columns which stretch everything else.